# Where is Cordbg?

Tags: windows-10, c++

I'm trying to debug a C++ application recently ported from linux, and I'm used to a command-line debugger. I'm not using Visual Studio, rather NMake Makefiles.

I hear `cordbg.exe` is a command line debugger I should have, but I can't find it.
I'm running Windows 10, and I have Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 3.5 installed.

Where is this file? If I don't have it, where can I get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Where can I get cordbg.exe?

You build it yourself (it is shipped as one of the sample applications provided with the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK).

> The Runtime Debugger helps tools vendors and application developers find and fix bugs in programs that target the .NET Framework common language runtime. This tool uses the runtime Debug API to provide debugging services.
>
> **The source code for Cordbg.exe is being shipped as a sample application.**
>
> Developers can examine the code to learn how to use the debugging services. Currently, you can only use Cordbg.exe to debug managed code; there is no support for debugging unmanaged code.

Source [Runtime Debugger (Cordbg.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zb7c8d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> [image]

Source [.NET Framework Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d9kh6s92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#debugTools)